# Non-static method called without instantiation in Unity using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was working with Unity and used an official tutorial which contained C# code that took the form as seen below:

```
public class P1_ActionController : MonoBehaviour 
{

  void FixedUpdate() 
  { 
   if (move > 0 && !facingRight) 
    {
     Flip();
    }
  }

  void Flip() 
  {
    //blah blah, something unimportant goes here.
  }

}
```

My question is, how is the FixedUpdate() method able to call the Flip() method directly? I thought only static methods can be used without instantiation but obviously Flip() is not a static method.

Also, in a related conundrum within the same code block is this line:

```
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpForce));
```

Being that the 'new' keyword is invoked on the Vector2() method, where exactly is Vector2() being instantiated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how is the FixedUpdate() method able to call the Flip() method directly?

Because `FixedUpdate` is an instance method, available only when the object is created. At which point, `Flip` is also available, since it is also an instance method. Its called all within the same instance of an object. When you're inside an instance method - you are within the scope of an actual object instance. That means you're able to call other instance methods or access other instance variables.

That said.. if `FixedUpdate` was `static`.. then this wouldn't work:

```
static void FixedUpdate() 
{ 
   if (move > 0 && !facingRight) 
   {
       Flip(); // BOOOM! CRASSSHHH!! Won't work
   }
}
```

To make that work, you would have to instantiate a new instance of your object from within the `static` method then invoke `Flip`. But, then, you wouldn't be able to share any common state both ways between the methods - the instance method could access `static` state, but not the vice versa.

> where exactly is Vector2() being instantiated

It is instantiated before the call to `AddForce` and passed in. This is just syntactic sugar and happens transparently.

Comment: Thanks Simon, that makes sense, except I can't visualize what part of the code is instantiating P1_ActionController in order to call FixedUpdate() and Flip()

Comment: `MonoBehaviour` derived classes are instantiated by the Unity engine and it calls methods on them every frame.